# Bluemix logging for python applications

Tags: python, logging, flask, ibm-cloud

I have a python application running on bluemix using python flask boilerplate. Is there any service I can use to have logging mechanism working for my application? Simple customized debug messages to debug my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluemix provides the [Monitoring and Analytics](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/monitoring-and-analytics/) service, but unfortunately for now it supports Liberty, Node.js, and Ruby-based applications. I think the best way is to use custom messages. Usually the Python developers use the Logging module, that has been a part of Python’s Standard Library since version 2.3. You could take a look at the [basic Logging how-to](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial). You will get the logs using the command:

```
cf logs <appName> --recent
```